# Adding script dynamic inside a div

Tags: jquery

I am using the code bellow to use Jquery UI slider.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
value:100,
min: 0,
max: 500,
step: 50,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
</script>
```

How is this possible to ad this script dynamicly inside a div by pressing a button?

```
<div id="addscript"></div>
```

I want to do this that way coz i am generating the slider and some text boxes dynamic like this way.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to execute the script when you press the button? If so you want to use the click event of the button and a function

Comment: Why don't you just put it in a function and call it on click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted at in my comment, you will want something like this, ensure you swap out 'button-id' for whatever ID is assigned to yours.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#button-id').on('click', function() {
            attachSlider();
        });
        function attachSlider() {
            $( "#slider" ).slider({
                value:100,
                min: 0,
                max: 500,
                step: 50,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
                }
            });
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No i already have a button and when i am pressing it i am adding a slider inside a div. next to each slider i have a div and i want to display a number when i am sliding the slider.. but i to work each slider seperately.

Comment: You have accepted my answer but I get the impression from this comment that you would like further assistance? Do you want me to create a jsfiddle for what you have described?